# I'm starting on React Js and got this error can anyone explain whats wrong?

Tags: reactjs

How can this be resolved i wanted to connect to another page is the navigation wrong or something else?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLZn3.png]

Answer (score 3):

Your `Home.js` file is in the same folder as `Vizag.js`. So the correct import path is `./Vizag`, not `./Pages/Vizag`.

`.` means the current directory, not the root of the project. (`..` means the parent directory)

Also, you don't need to specify the `.js` extension in your imports.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write **import Vizag from './Vizag.js'** as this file is in the same location as well as folder.